# How to send an email via Mailgun with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, mailgun

I'm trying to send via mailgun API in angularjs but it's not working here is my code snippet:

```
console.log('step1');

    var mailgunUrl = "DOMAIN_NAME";
    var mailgunApiKey = window.btoa("api:key-API_KEY")

    $scope.send = function () {
        console.log('in here');
        $http({
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/" + mailgunUrl + "/messages",
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Authorization": "Basic " + mailgunApiKey
            },
            data: "from=" + "test@example.com" + "&to=" + "TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS" + "&subject=" + "MailgunTest" + "&text=" + "EmailBody"
        }).then(function (success) {
            console.log("SUCCESS " + JSON.stringify(success));
        }, function (error) {
            console.log("ERROR " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }

    console.log('step last');
```

it console "step1" and "step last" but its not sending mail.

Can you please help me out or suggest what I can do here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you add to meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```